# JXL Api Throwing an error while reading MS Excel 2013 generated Excel File

Tags: java, excel, jxl

I have a "test.xlsx" file created via MS Excel 2013. When I tried to read this via JXL API as below

```
public Workbook readExcel(File inputWorkbook) {
        Workbook workbook= null;
        try {
            workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputWorkbook);
            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
            for (int j = 0; j < sheet.getColumns(); j++) {
                for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getRows(); i++) {
                    Cell cell = sheet.getCell(j, i);
                    CellType type = cell.getType();
                    if (type == CellType.LABEL) {
                        System.out.println("I got a label "
                                + cell.getContents());
                    }

                    if (type == CellType.NUMBER) {
                        System.out.println("I got a number "
                                + cell.getContents());
                    }

                }
            }
        } catch (BiffException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return workbook ;
    }
```

I am getting  "**jxl.read.biff.BiffException: Unable to recognize OLE stream**" 
When I am saving this file as 1997-2003 .xls then program runs fine.

I wanted to know if JXL api has limitation that it cannot read MS 2013 Excel programs ?

If someOne solved this issue please let me know

Comment: I did some analysis and didnt find the solution till now. because of urgency for functionality to support I have to use another POI API.  It solved my problem It can now read the MSExcel 2013 excelsheets also

Comment: to see how to use this API to Read/Write to Excel file ,  you can visit  http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/